# MS Access ignores confirmation dialog when updating linked MySQL table

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access, odbc

I have a MySQL database (Version 5.1.63) which is connected to MS Access (2002) via ODBC (MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver).

In MySQL I created a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `col` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col`)
);
```

and one example row:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`col`, `stamp`) VALUES
(4, '2012-07-17 13:25:29');
```

When I link the table to Access and update the entry with a query:

```
UPDATE test SET test.col = 6;
```

Access will open a dialog asking to confirm the update. But whatever I choose (yes or no) it will update the table anyway. 
WHY? Does anybody know how to fix this?